# How to correctly extend expiration of JWT token in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-jwt

I need to improve the JWT token logic to extend expiration each time, when I will call any REST API request. For this purpose, I was created a method to extend jwt expiration to next 60 seconds, each time, when the method is called:

```
  /**
   * Method to extend the token expiration
   * @param oldToken
   */
  extendTokenExpiration(oldToken: string) {
    const decoded = this.jwtService.decode(oldToken);
    decoded.exp = decoded.exp + 60;
    try {
      const newToken = this.jwtService.sign(decoded, {
        secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      });
      console.log('New token:', newToken);
      return newToken;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error:', e);
    }
  }
```

Problem is, that still I will receive an following error:

```
 Error: Bad "options.expiresIn" option the payload already has an "exp" property.
```

If I will manually delete the `decoded.exp` prop and add `expiresIn` into the options, the error disappears, but expiration if this jwt token still stay the same (expiration is not extended).

Thanks a lot for an each help.

Comment: You are not suppose to do that to a JWT token. Consider Access Token and Refresh Token. Access Token have a limited ttl while Refresh Token have a longer ttl. 
You need to refresh the Access Token each time with Refresh Token

Comment: Hi @itssajan, thanks a lot for your help. Does exists for that any documentation? Because on NestJs there are only base information. Also what is making me little headache is, how to make sync state between frontend and backend (to know on frontend, if I have still valid /not expired/ credentials)

Comment: try this link, https://www.elvisduru.com/blog/nestjs-jwt-authentication-refresh-token

Comment: if you are using frontend api calls using axios then you can intercept each request and watch the status. if status is 401 then you can add the refresh logic and update the token then retry the previous request.